# how to create folder view type gallery?

Tags: android, gallery, directory, thumbnails

Hi I have created one gallery view...its working fine but my gallery view displays images in single row of images. i want all the images to be inside the folder...and folder should display thumbnails of images...please help how to create that type of gallery.....